# how to upload file to kinvey using flex services?

Tags: kinvey

Im new to Kinvey flex services but i need to use flex to upload files to Kinveys file storage.

I cannot find any information about flex services and files. is any one can show me example of how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no helper module available in FlexServices for file uploads at the moment, but you can just call the REST API for files directly from within a FlexService.